# Calculate actual size needed for a MATLAB uicontrol

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I'm trying to calculate the actual size needed for uicontrols in a GUI so the GUI can resize itself appropriately. My problem is that the Extent property of a uicontrol is only the text area, and I can't find a way to determine the size of the surrounding control (such as the down arrow in a popup or the margin of an edit control). Is there a way to get the size of the decorations on a control?

I saw [this related question](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/383-slider-appearance-on-macs-in-a-cross-platform-gui) on MATLAB Answers, which looked like it ended with no solution as well.

*Edit:*

For example, I want to calculate how big this popup should be to avoid cutting off the contents:

```
uicontrol('style', 'popup', 'string', {'a long string'})
```

Extent only tells me how big "a long string" is, and I still don't know how big to make the popup. I want a way to determine how much extra space is needed on the user's display (without assuming which OS or font sizes they use).

Answer (score 1):

You can use get(hObject,'extent') to find out how much space the string contained in the uicontrol takes up. You can see if this is larger than the uicontrol's position.

Comment: As I noted in my question, the extent property only tells you the space occupied by the string. The control surrounding the string needs additional space. If position is equal to extent, the control is already too small.

Answer (score 0):

The uicontrol [Position](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxoipv) property gives you the height and width of the bounding rectangle for the control. This has always worked for me. Is there a control where this property does not provide enough information?

Comment: Position only tells you the current size of the control. It doesn't tell you anything about the size the control needs to be. I edited the question to add an example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the GUI you're building can be assembled exclusively from Java components, you can use MATLAB's Java integration to create and drive a window using Java Swing components (all from M-code). That sidesteps the problem entirely, since the Java layout managers can do UI layout properly.